# My woodworker is ignoring my woodpile

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So I'm using the [linked tutorial](https://afteractionreporter.com/2009/02/10/the-complete-and-utter-newby-tutorial-for-dwarf-fortress-part-3-%E2%80%9Cdwarf-whatnow%E2%80%9D/) and just trundling along when I noticed that my barrel production is practically nonexistent. Instead of using the woodpile next to him, my woodworker is going all the way up to the surface to get wood. I've had a look in the orders, and couldn't find anything regarding wood piles (other than dwarfs gathering them).

Any ideas?

[image: Dwarf Fortress Woodpile issue]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given the information you have here there are several possibilities:

The [distance estimation](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Path) to resources doesn't take intervening walls etc. into account. So If this is just a few z-levels below the surface and the wood is right above the shop, then the woodworker actually thinks that the surface wood is closer despite having to go the long way around to get it.

If you have any [burrows](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Burrow) set up then they could exclude the worker from using some resources. However it does not look like you are at a stage where you would have started messing around with burrows.

The workshop could be linked to a stockpile on the surface, if the wood on the surface is in a stockpile.

To fix this you have a few options:

- You can set the workshop to only take from the one stockpile you want using the building options, as djsmiley noted.
- You could move all the wood down to this wood stockpile.
- You could move the workshop next to the stockpile, which would also give time gains on correct hauling.
- You could set up a burrow to contain the wood stockpile and the workshop, and anything else the carpenter needs to do(like eat), but not the surface wood, and then assign the carpenter to it.

My personal suggestion would be to move the workshop closer to the correct stockpile.

Comment: Upvoted or completeness. i totally forgot burrows :O

Comment: Errr, could a woodchop order interfere with a woodworkers capability to use piles?(as in, he would go out to chop wood, and use that log for the barrel)

Comment: It's worth noting that the closest wood on the same floor is 16 squares away, while the surface is a mere 3 squares away. Most likely the cause is the distance estimation calculation.  I always build all workshops directly next to a stairwell, with the resources they need in smallish piles directly above and below them, and the output usually either above or below those. Then use stockpile orders to fill inputs and empty outputs to/from bigger piles elsewhere.  Dwarves _love_ to use stairwells.

Answer (score 6):

You could force the carpenter workshop to take wood from this pile, I have a feeling  you may of accidentally limited it to only give to specific workshops?

This is achieved via the q key and then checking the 'take from..' options.

Comment: I don't see that option. Got Add, Cancel, Promote, Repeat, Suspend, Profile and Remove o.O

Comment: Pretty sure the "take from" is a stockpile option, for moving from one pile to another. Last I checked, workshops had no such option. (It's been years since I played, my info may be out of date)

Comment: You can set a stockpile to "give to" a workshop( http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Stockpile#Give_to_a_stockpile.2Fworkshop ). Then the workshop has an option to only accept materials from links. But you might need a manager to change that setting, I don't quite remember.

Comment: To tell a workshop to pull from a specific stockpile (rather than an order to the stockpile to the workshop), use the q (Set Building Tasks/Prefs) key on the workshop and then select the pile to pull from.